# Word for feeling one gets when someone else gets just punisment

Tags: single-word-requests

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171544/idiom-for-the-phrase-someone-who-gets-what-he-deserved) asks for an idiom for someone getting what they deserve. But what about the feeling one gets when someone else gets "what they deserve"? Is there a specific word or expression for the good feeling you get when justice is served?

Comment: Depending on whether you love or hate, support or jeopardize and likewise, there are many possibilities.

Comment: @Rathony I've made it clearer

Comment: Bob commits a crime. Bob deserves punishment and he gets it. On hearing about Bob, Marley feels (word). Is that what you meant? Now, is the feeling sad or happy?

Comment: @NVZ Yes, it is

Comment: @NVZ Sorry, that's something you edited in afterwards right? Anyway, she's feeling happy: "good feeling you get when justice is served"

Answer (score 1):

Albeit only negative...

**Schadenfreude** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/schadenfreude)

> *noun* 1. satisfaction or pleasure felt at someone else's misfortune.

Answer (score 0):

Some I would use:

**satisfaction**
satɪsˈfakʃ(ə)n/

> *noun*
>   fulfilment of one's wishes, expectations, or needs, or the pleasure derived from this.

**triumph**
ˈtrʌɪʌmf/

> *noun*
>   a great victory or achievement.

**gratification**
ɡratɪfɪˈkeɪʃn/

> *noun*
>   pleasure, especially when gained from the satisfaction of a desire.

---

Although it would no longer be a single word, you could prefix these with something like *Karmic* to really enforce the reason behind the feeling.